# Connecting to MQTT broker (Mosquitto) installed on a Raspberry Pi over the Internet

Tags: raspbian, mqtt, raspberry-pi2, mosquitto

I am planning to create a very simple home\office monitoring system, where I will be able to connect sensors using Mosquitto broker on a Raspberry Pi. The sensors will publish data to the broker and I will be able to see the data as a subscriber.

I have a publisher that periodically publishes messages to the Raspberry Pi (Mosquitto broker) in the house in the same LAN network. But I want to connect a sensor that will be located at my office to the same broker, so the connection can't be except online.

The problem that I am facing at the moment is that I want to connect a sensor to the Raspberry Pi but I need to do it over the Internet given the limitations of hardware. How do I connect the sensor to publish to the broker that resides in the Raspberry Pi from outside the LAN network? I just checked and my public IP address could have thousands of addresses underneath it, how do I know which one is me and connect to it?!

Comment: Just publish to the IP address of the broker. That's the point of IP addresses. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: You need to explain you network layout, I could make assumptions about NAT routers or Dynamic IP addresses but you need to explain the problem better

Comment: @EmilVikström Wow awesome suggestion, and I didn't know how come I din't think of it. But found out that I can't do so unless if I am connected to the same LAN network. Which is not the case as I am connected through wifi. So that's where I am stuck at the moment, it tells me that it failed to publish..

Comment: @hardillb Thank you sir. At the moment as a subscriber I am just looking forward to be able to get access to the network remotely, without the need to be in the same LAN network as the Raspberry Pi. Do I need to explain further? The problem I am facing at the moment is that I am not able to connect to the Raspberry Pi freely from anywhere online, except if I am in the same LAN network.

Comment: No, still no where enough detail. Edit the question (no not add more comments) with a detailed description of the network layout.

Comment: Done @hardillb. Thank you for notifying me. And please let me know if I missed anything.

Comment: @hardillb I hope you can help me sir :x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Somewhat depends on your home network. If your ISP uses so called "[Carrier Grade NAT](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Carrier-grade_NAT)" which is increasingly common due to the fact that few IPv4 addresses are now available, you cannot make a connection from the Internet to your local network.

Otherwise you can make a connection inwards and so your remote sensor just needs a TCP/IP connection. *We would need more information on the sensor to show you how to do that*. To find your public IP address, you visit https://www.whatismyip.com/ from a computer on your local network. (*To find out if you are stuck with carrier grade nat, ask your ISP or do a reverse lookup on your public IP address, you may be able to tell*). You will also need to configure the firewall on your router so that it allows inbound connections to a PORT that you choose (on the outside) and map that to the internal IP address of the Pi and the port configured on Mosquitto for handling MQTT traffic.

For carrier grade NAT or if you cannot configure your router's firewall to allow incoming connections, you should use another MQTT broker on the Internet somewhere. Then configure your Pi broker to *bridge* to the Internet broker.

The [Owntracks documentation](http://owntracks.org/booklet/guide/bridge/) has a quick tutorial. There is also information in the Mosquitto documentation on how to do this.

In this case, your Pi broker is making a connection out to the internet which works fine on any WAN if you are not excessively blocking outgoing traffic.

**In either case, do not forget that any traffic over the Internet is insecure. You will need to set up SSL certificates along with a username/password combination to secure the traffic.**

Comment: Thanks sir. Awesome answer. I forgot to mention that I am connected by university's Internet, which means that I don't get to do port forwarding. Thus your suggestion to make a connection between the brokers is really good and I hopefully get it solves my problem soon. Although it would mean extra latency in the network.

Comment: Glad to help. Note that latency isn't a problem with MQ systems, you don't expect them to be instant anyway.

Comment: I want to ask then, the other broker that is on the Internet somewhere, is it supposed to be mine and hence I have to configure it myself? Or can I use the test servers by mosquitto and paho?

Comment: I wouldn't use test servers as they may not always work. There are public MQTT services however with free plans. Fine for casual stuff where you aren't too worried about security. e.g. CloudMQTT or ThingMQ.

Answer (score 2):

Easy!

- Just add a port forwarding (in your local router 192.168.x.x) to your raspberrPi ip and MQTT (usually port 1883).
- Then your sensor should be connected to internet and send a topic/payload to your public IP address at home...

I do this for android apps
- owntrack
- juiceSSH
- raspicheck
- myMQTT
- openHAB
- Yatse (For Kodi remote)

But do not forget when you open a port you will need to secure it access somehow...
and your public i.p. can be automatically change by your ISP (InternetServiceProvider)

Comment: Doesn't work if you are behind carrier-grade NAT. This is increasingly common and mandated in some countries. You might be able to get round it with IPv6 but that is generally a nightmare to get working.